# Why does my jest mock implementation work as the second argument to jest.mock(), but gives errors when abstracted to the __mocks__ folder?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, typescript, jestjs, azure-functions

I am attempting to mock the `mssql` library for JEST testing my typescript nodejs Azure Functions (v3). To do so, I wrote the following test file:

```js
import httpTrigger from "./index";
import {
    BindingDefinition,
    functionRunner,
    HttpBinding,
} from "stub-azure-function-context";
import { describe, expect, jest, test, beforeEach } from "@jest/globals";
import functionJSON from "./function.json";

const bindings = functionJSON.bindings as BindingDefinition[];

jest.mock("mssql", () => {
    let mockRecordset = [{
        ContactID: 123456,
        FirstName: "Test",
        EmailAddress: "testman@gmail.com",
        Number: "123-456-7890",
        AzureID: "az1234",
        HideAmountOwed: false,
    }];
    
    const mockQuery = jest.fn(() => ({
        recordset: mockRecordset,
    }));
    const mockInput = jest.fn(() => ({
        query: mockQuery,
    }));
    const mockRequest = jest.fn(() => ({
        input: mockInput,
    }));
    
    return {
    ConnectionPool: jest.fn(() => ({
        connect: jest.fn(),
        request: mockRequest,
    })),
    NVarChar: jest.fn(),
}});

describe("GetContact", () => {
    test("returns status 400 when not provided with a contactID or azureID", async () => {
        const bindingData = {
            req: new HttpBinding({
                method: "GET",
            }),
        };
        const context = await functionRunner(
            httpTrigger,
            bindings,
            bindingData
        );

        expect(context.res.status).toBe(400);
    });
});
```

This appears to work. However when I extract it to a **`__mocks__`**folder, like this:

```js
const mock = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() =>{
    let mockRecordset = [
        {
            ContactID: 123456,
            FirstName: "Test",
            EmailAddress: "testman@gmail.com",
            Number: "123-456-7890",
            AzureID: "az1234",
            HideAmountOwed: false,
        },
    ];

    const mockQuery = jest.fn(() => ({
        recordset: mockRecordset,
    }));
    const mockInput = jest.fn(() => ({
        query: mockQuery,
    }));
    const mockRequest = jest.fn(() => ({
        input: mockInput,
    }));

    return {
        ConnectionPool: jest.fn(() => ({
            connect: jest.fn(),
            request: mockRequest,
        })),
        NVarChar: jest.fn(),
    };
});

export default mock;
```

and omit the second arg of `jest.mock` like so...

```js
import httpTrigger from "./index";
import {
    BindingDefinition,
    functionRunner,
    HttpBinding,
} from "stub-azure-function-context";
import { describe, expect, jest, test, beforeEach } from "@jest/globals";
import functionJSON from "./function.json";

const bindings = functionJSON.bindings as BindingDefinition[];

jest.mock("mssql");

describe("GetContact", () => {
    test("returns status 400 when not provided with a contactID or azureID", async () => {
        const bindingData = {
            req: new HttpBinding({
                method: "GET",
            }),
        };
        const context = await functionRunner(
            httpTrigger,
            bindings,
            bindingData
        );

        expect(context.res.status).toBe(400);
    });
});
```

it now gives the following error:

```
 FAIL  dist/GetContact/index.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: mssql_1.default.ConnectionPool is not a constructor

       5 | const useTestDb = process.env.USE_TEST_DB === 'true';
       6 |
    >  7 | const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(useTestDb ? testConString : prodConString);
         |              ^
       8 | if (useTestDb) {
       9 |     console.log('!!! USING TEST DATABASE');
      10 | }
```

Why is it suddenly causing it to "not be a constructor"? How do I properly convert a moduleFactory argument into a **mocks** item which can be shared?